# "Ghost Marks" issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, render

I dont know what the technical term for this is but I decided to use the term "Ghost Marks" to describe it. This is done using Chrome.

Using Bootstrap I have two tabs. There is more content in the first tab so the container is longer than the second tab. Outside (below) the tabs container there is another div with some text and a green button.

Sometimes when I click between the two tabs "Ghost Marks" of the div outside the container are left on the page. This is occurring because when I switch from the larger tab to the smaller tab the div outside the container moves up the page leaving marks as it goes along.

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image: Ghost Marks]

It has something to do with the way chrome paints the HTML. If I press F12 the Ghost marks disappear.

I could make the 2nd tabs container the same height as the first tabs container but that would leave a lot of white space.

Any ideas how to make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm guessing your device is acting up. Got a lot of active programs?

Comment: Nope, just visual studio and chrome.

Comment: I tend to agree with Martijn. It may either the browser or the system. I don't think it is a coding issue.

Comment: It must be a Chrome render issue because if you force a repaint by pressing F12 the marks disappear. I dont think there's anything wrong with my system.